# WSL distribution not registering in airgapped computer

Tags: windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have been following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual) to try and get Windows Subsystem for Linux to work on an airgapped computer.   Files are being transferred via a USB drive.

- I installed Windows 11 Pro on a laptop with both Ethernet and Wifi adapeters disabled in the BIOS.  Activated by phone.  The laptop has 16 GB of ram, which should be plenty.
- I got through steps 1 through 5, running the two dism commands, installing the kernel update, and finally setting wsl version 2 as the default.
- **At this point, the instructions failed.** You obviously can't use the Store part of step 6, but there's a section for downloading distributions manually.  But the page gives downloads for `AppxBundle` files, not `appx` files mentioned in later steps.
- On the other hand, the AppxBundle file just contains a bunch of different Appx packages for different platforms, and running it selects the one for the correct platform and runs that one. So,
- I downloaded `Ubuntu2204-221101.AppxBundle` (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) and copied it to the airgapped computer.
- I ran `Add-AppxPackage` on the bundle and double-clicked the bundle to install it. The distribution thought it installed successfully.

However, upon launch nothing happens.  `wsl -l` says no distributions are installed.
Event Viewer shows numerous errors of the form

```
0x800704CF: Cannot create the process for package CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_2204.1.7.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc because an error was encountered while preparing for activation. [LaunchProcess]
```

I tried downloading and installing the Kali distribution, with the same result.

I tried the alternate instructions given by @ramhound in comments, with the same result.

I guess something needs Internet access (the error code relates to a network address that can't be reached), but that would defeat the purpose of this exercise, which is to create an airgapped system.

**UPDATE**: Every time I try to use an Appx or AppxBundle, the distribution fails to register due to the lack of a network connection.
A commenter asserted that they got an offline-downloaded appx file to work but didn't provide any advice except "follow the instructions"
which AFAICT, I did.

**However**, if I install a distro from the Microsoft Store into WSL on a networked system, then export it and import it into the airgapped system, I can get a working WSL subsystem; I may have to go with that unless someone provides an explanation of what is happening.

Comment: If someone could create and link an [tag:air-gap] tag for me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What happens when you run `ubuntu2204.exe`?  Is that how you are launching right now?

Comment: @Spencer - The tag in my opinion is unnecessary.  The question body makes it clear you need a solution that works offline. The tag wouldn't make it easier to find your WSL2 question.

Comment: Any event, can you provide, the exact commands you ran? I presume you used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#downloading-distributions) to download the distribution? if not then the process you followed is uncleared and should be clarified by editing your question

Comment: From the page you linked to: "Once the Appx package has finished downloading, you can start running the new distribution by double-clicking the appx file. (**The command `wsl -l` will not show that the distribution is installed until this step is complete**)."

Comment: @BenVoigt It's at that stage that it should run `ubuntu2204.exe`.  Since the OP mentioned that *"The distribution thought it installed successfully"*, I'm fairly confident they launched the `appx`.  Also, the errors in the log (`Cannot create the process for package CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_2204.1.7.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc`) definitely wouldn't be appearing if the `appx` hadn't been executed.  Something's definitely gone wrong, and I'm not expecting `ubuntu2204.exe` to *work*, just perhaps give us a different message.

Comment: Funny that the OP hasn't mentioned doing that, according to them the last thing before failure was copying the `AppxBundle` file.

Comment: According to the directions I found the file should have a .apx extension instead of Appxbundle, see one potential reason, the filename from Microsoft is actually **Appxbundle.zip**

Comment: @Ramhound An AppXBundle is just a container for some `.appx` files --when you run the bundle, it picks the correct one for the platform and runs that (and that's what is supposed to run the exe). Edits in the morning.

Comment: @Spencer - I am aware. I was just pointing out the instructions mentioned a different file extension. I can attest following the instructions on the linked page absolutely work for a completely isolated offline Windows installation.

Comment: @Ramhound I guess the instructions are incomplete then, because an appx file was not provided on the page.  If you got it to work, you must have performed some additional task not spelled out in the instructions?

Comment: I downloaded the AppxBundle and downloaded the file with an appx extension, both instances, when I select Open results in the distribution opening.

Comment: @Ramhound Where did you get the file with the appx extension? Did you extract it from the AppxBundle?

Comment: I followed the directions on the Microsoft website.

Comment: @Ramhound Which direction, specifically?  I can't see one that gets you an .appx file.  That section of manual downloads only gives .AppXBundle files.

Comment: I ran *Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/wslubuntu2004 -OutFile Ubuntu.appx -UseBasicParsing*, when I selected “open” after it completed downloading I was presented the exact same dialog that I received from the .Appxbundle file I had downloaded by using a browser.

Comment: @Ramhound You selected "open" _after downloading_... anyway, that detail should be in the answer you post.

Comment: I've flagged my question as a duplicate of: https://superuser.com/questions/1118732/is-it-possible-to-install-wsl-with-no-internet-connection

Comment: @Spencer - I submitted a comment not an answer. You also said in your question you launched it, when I took as, you also selected "open".

Comment: @Ramhound I suggest you post an answer, as you have information that isn't spelled out in the linked page.   Also, see the other Super User question I linked to.

Comment: @Spencer - I wouldn't have anything to write, I downloaded the file from Microsoft, and then right clicked on the file and selected Open. I literally didn't do anything beyond that.

Comment: @Ramhound The thing is, you say you opened the file after downloading it. How did you download the file onto a disconnected system?

Comment: @Spencer - I downloaded the file on my host machine and transferred it to a VM with a disabled network adapter. I also just selected Open, I didn't actually installed it, I didn't see the purpose since I was asking you if you had used that method or not. At the time I had not semi-confirmed you should be exporting the machine then importing it on the machine without access to the Microsoft Store through additional research and past Super User questions on the subject.